# Google Maps V3 cannot call function from infowindow

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have created a zoom function for my Google maps:

function zoomIn(){

map.setZoom(parseInt(map.getZoom())+2)

}

I keep on getting a 'Object expected' error when I try to call it. When I debug this

Error: zoomIn is not defined

Source File: javascript:zoomIn()

Any ideas of why this is happening is much appreciated.

The map can be seen using the link below, the function is located on line 189

http://tinyurl.com/3ryuxvy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is with function scope.  You define the `zoomIn` function inside `initialize`.  When the user clicks on the control to zoom in and `zoomIn()` is called it is looking for `zoomIn` on the global `window` object but it doesn't exist there.

To fix this you need to refactor your javascript so `zoomIn` is available in the global scope.  This could mean implementing the function outside of `initialize()`.

Read more about JS scoping here: http://www.digital-web.com/articles/scope_in_javascript/

Comment: I have been readind up on scope etc already and had tried to put the function outside of initize but then I was getting 'map is undefined' even though I made the map a global variable

Comment: I thought I have made the map global by using var, didnt realise i had it the wrong way round